# How can I insert Postgres rows using Power Automate from a PowerBI Table?

Tags: power-automate, powerbi

**Problem:**  In Power Automate I cannot get the rows from a PowerBI table source - using the 'First table rows' to populate the **Insert Row** (Postres) Action in order to insert the rows into my postgres table.

FYI I have a successful Power Automate flow to export a csv from a PowerBI table using the 'First table rows' so I know it has the data I want. I'm trying to setup a parallel branch to insert rows to a postgres table- the same data that is exported to csv.

Attempt at the parallel Branch (left side has the csv which works, right side is the new postgres section):
[image]

For the Postgres branch I believe I need to read the 'First table rows' and I have assumed I need the **Select** Action and have a mapping:

```
Key:   project_name 
Value: item()?['Project Name']
```

For the key I'm assuming it should be the column name in my destination postgres table.

[image]

For the 'value' I have also tried:

```
item()?['PM- Data Governance Projects[Project Name]']
```

(which includes the source PowerBI Table name, but same result- I assumed that this table name wouldn't be required)

When we get to the **Insert Rows** Action, I was expecting to get Dynamic text coming from the **Select** action allowing me to choose from the mapped column names but there's nothing. It's just as empty as the **Select** Dynamic/Expression input boxes.

The only way I managed to insert a new row was by manually entering an idx (my numeric Primary key column). I'm hoping that this may prove it's not a permissions issue - or could there still be an issue?

[image]

However, all other columns were blank despite entering these values either in the **Select** Action or the **Insert Row** action:

```
item()?['id']
item()?['Project Name']
item()?['Title']
item()?['Description']
item()?['Category']
item()?['Start Date']
item()?['Due Date']
```

Does anyone know how to get the column values through to postgres?